# How can I fix this Q.denodify test?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q, sinon

I am using a database library that its callback-based interface looks like this:

```
var DB = {
    insert: function(options, callback) {

    }
}
```

I want to implement a wrapper around this database to convert its callback style API to a promise based API. To do this I have defined the following class:

```
var DatabaseWrapper = {
    init: function(db) {
        this.db = db;
    },
    insert: function(options) {
        return Q.denodeify(this.db.insert.bind(this.db))(options);
    }
}
```

I want to write a unit test to ensure that when I call `DatabaseWrapper.insert` it calls `DB.insert`. So far my test looks like this:

```
describe('DatabaseWrapper', function () {
    var wrapper, insertSpy, bindStub;

    beforeEach(function () {
        wrapper = Object.create(DatabaseWrapper);
        insertSpy = sinon.spy(function () {
            console.log('insertSpy got called');
        });
        bindStub = sinon.stub();

        wrapper.db = {
            insert: function (options, callback) {
            }
        };

        sinon.stub(wrapper.db.insert, 'bind').returns(insertSpy);
    });


    describe('#insert', function () {
        it('should delegate to db.insert', function (done) {
            wrapper.insert({herp: 'derp'});

            expect(wrapper.db.insert.bind).to.have.been.calledOnce;

            // This fails but I expect it to succeed
            expect(promise).to.have.been.calledOnce;
        })
    });
});
```

The DB instance's insert method is actually getting called as after the test fails, as the `'insertSpy got called'` message is printed in the console.

But apparently it gets called after the test has failed.

As far as I know, this is due to the way Node's `process.nextTick` works. So the call to the callback happens after the test fails. Is there a way I can fix this test without relying on third-party libraries (e.g. [`q-flush`](https://github.com/bahmutov/q-flush))?

Comment: It's an asynchronous test - use the asynchronous promise syntax.

Comment: @Benjamin could you please provide the solution as an answer?

Comment: Are you using Mocha for your tests?

Comment: Yes I'm using Mocha.

Comment: Ok, please add the mocha tag to your question and I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're performing an asynchronous action so it's best to perform an asynchronous test. Adding a `setTimeout` still leaves you prone to race conditions.

```
describe('#insert', function () {
        it('should delegate to db.insert', function () { // no done here
            // note the return here to signal to mocha this is a promise test 
            return wrapper.insert({herp: 'derp'}).then(function(){
              // add expects here, rest of asserts should happen here
              expect(wrapper.db.insert.bind).to.have.been.calledOnce;   
            }); 
        })
    });
});
```